# How can I change radio buttons to mat-toogle-group

Tags: angular

I need to write below radio button code to mat-toggle-group

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="certRqrd" value="true" #cert=ngModel [(ngModel)]="modalData.certificationReq"
    (change)="certRqrChange()" required> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="certRqrd" value="false" #cert=ngModel [(ngModel)]="modalData.certificationReq"
    (change)="certRqrChange()" required> No
</div>
```

I have written like this but it is not working

```
<div>
  <mat-button-toggle-group name="certRqrd" #group="matButtonToggleGroup" [(ngModel)]="modalData.certificationReq">
    <mat-button-toggle [value]="true" (change)="certRqrChange()">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle [value]="false" (change)="certRqrChange()">No</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `modalData.certificationReq` defined as public? What is its datatype? This seems working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjzwry?file=src/app/button-toggle-exclusive-example.html

Comment: modeldata is array type it is the variable which i am storing the data which comes from backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If modalData is array, than you should set model with using of modalData indexed element
like:

```
 [(ngModel)]="modalData[0].certificationReq"
```

or, if you working with whole array than use *ngFor cycle like

```
<div *ngFor="let element of modalData">
   <mat-button-toggle-group name="certRqrd"  #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
        [(ngModel)]="element.certificationReq"  >
     <mat-button-toggle [value]="true" (change)="certRqrChange()">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
     <mat-button-toggle [value]="false" (change)="certRqrChange()">No</mat-button-toggle>
   </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

**UPD:**

For your *.html

```html
<div style="width: 300px; display: block">
    <mat-label>certificationReq - </mat-label>
    <mat-button-toggle-group name="certRqrd" #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
                             [(ngModel)]="modalData.certificationReq">
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="true" (change)="certRqrChange()">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="false" (change)="certRqrChange()">No</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
    <hr>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="certVer" [(ngModel)]="modalData.certVer" [required]="true">
    </mat-form-field>
    <hr>
    <mat-label>certFulFld - </mat-label>
    <mat-button-toggle-group name="certFulFld" #group2="matButtonToggleGroup"
                             [(ngModel)]="modalData.certFulFld" [required]="true">
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="true">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="false">No</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
  </div>
```

For your *.ts file

```js
  modalData: any = {
    certificationReq: null,
    certFulFld: null,
    certVer: null
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    // getting flag value;
    this.getCertRqrdInitialValue();
  }


  getCertRqrdInitialValue() {
    /* 
      code of getting modalData.certificationReq
      for example set value to false
    */
    this.modalData.certificationReq = false;
    this.certRqrChange();
  }

  certRqrChange() {
    // set logic to what you want
    if (!this.modalData.certificationReq) {
      this.modalData.certFulFld = true;
      this.modalData.certVer = null;
    } else {
      this.modalData.certFulFld = null;
      this.modalData.certVer = null;
    }
    console.debug(this.modalData);
  }
```

Comment: sorry modalData is of any type and I need to code for below secnario.
there are two more fields certVer(input text) and certFulFld(mat-button-toogle-group) which I added manually. where as certificationReq comes from service.

1)If certificationReq is NO then certVer should be none and certFulFld should be YES.
2)If certificationReq is Yes then certVer should need entry and certFulFld should need entry.